# Who's the character in the middle of this WIXOSS cast picture?

Tags: wixoss

[Take a look at this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kz8B.jpg), which I have not embedded in this post because it contains some spoilers for the end of season 2 of WIXOSS. It turns out that this is a drawing by [Yakou Hiroshi](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=44597) (posted [here on Twitter](https://twitter.com/dakenmukuinugam/status/545983859414687745) and [here on pixiv](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=47642274)), who was an animation director for WIXOSS. So not quite "official art", per se, but very close to it.

Who is the person in the middle of the picture (to the right of Hitoe, beneath Hanayo, and left of Yuzuki)?

I can identify everyone else in the picture, but I have no recollection of seeing this person. I think every important character in the series is in the picture, too (heck, even Ruuko's brother and the card shop lady are in there). The most important person I can think of who isn't in the picture is Hitoe's mom, and that clearly ain't her...

Comment: looks like she appears in the OP at [0:50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Is-kXZDsZ8#t=50s) as the middle of the trio on the bottom right.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ Well, I'll be darned, that sure does look like the same person. Nice catch! Still dunno who that is, though - maybe one of Yuzuki's classmates that harassed her about her relationship with Kazuki?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Her name is Honoka. She's a part of Kazuki's circle of friends. In episode 6 of the first season she and a couple of other girls confront Yuzuki about her relationship with her brother. In episode 8 she leads Kazuki out from the card shop where they're playing together in order to confesses her feelings to him. When she's rejected, she tells him what people have been saying behind his back.